# UnsupportedClassVersionError When Running JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm getting a `UnsupportedClassVersionError` error when calling `FindClass()` when running my C++ application on RedHat Linux.  We're a C++ shop and  we're using JNI in order to use a Java library given to us by a third party broker to interface with their systems.

The program had not been recompiled in a couple of years but recently an older C++ library that the program used was deprecated so we had to recompile this program.  But now when we try to run the program we're getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: TradingEngineWrapper : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
```

I tried upgrading to a newer version of the JDK (jdk1.8.0_45) but that didn't help.  I know this is caused because our Java class library is compiled with one version but the JRE that is being invoked by the JNI is an incompatible version.  My question is, how do I control what version of the JRE that gets called when starting my C++ application?  Because I'm calling a C++ application I'm not starting it with "java app_name" or anything like that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide any code that you are using? Debugging with out code is nearly impossible.

Comment: The JRE is an *older* version. You need to either upgrade it or compile with an older JDK or the -version switch. @Whitecat No code necessary to discern that.